# Contextual type 'Any' cannot be used with dictionary literal Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I use this code in two files, but only one file shows this error.

> Contextual type 'Any' cannot be used with dictionary literal

Why? This 2 code is the same, why only one got the error? What's wrong in this code?

```
let userId = user!["userId"] as! String
let bookCid = NSUUID().uuidString
let param = ["message":"addAccBook",
                 "accountbook":
                    [
                        "bookcid": bookCid!,
                        "accbookname": "",
                        "accbooktype": "",
                        "category": "",
                        "user": userId
    ]] as [String:Any]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try rebuilding?

Comment: Ya, I close the project and open again, still got the error. I also paste the code on playground, it will show the error so I wonder why there is no error in the AddAccBookVC.swift and what's wrong the code..

Comment: Show the declaration of `bookCid` in the _AddAccBookVC_. Is it an optional String?

Answer (score 4):

The error is misleading. The actual error is

> Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'String'

`uuidString` returns an non-optional `String`, therefore you must not add an exclamation mark

```
let userId = user!["userId"] as! String
let bookCid = NSUUID().uuidString

let param : [String:Any] = ["message":"addAccBook",
                            "accountbook":
                               ["bookcid": bookCid,
                                "accbookname": "",
                                "accbooktype": "",
                                "category": "",
                                "user": userId]]
```

Rather than bridge cast the type I recommend to annotate it.

Comment: That's what fixed it for me. Having said that how do we go about making the error shown by Xcode actually relevant to what is causing the issue?